# Merge two partitions from different dev/sdb on USB

Tags: linux, partition, usb, kde, kubuntu

So I have a Kubuntu installation on my USB but the problem was that I formatted/split the disk space wrongly. This caused my Linux installation to have almost no disk space to use while my leftover disk space is wasted to my "USB storage" partition that I don't really use.

[image: Partitions]

So I was wondering what is the best way to reformat the sdb1 partition so that I can use as extra space for my sdb2 partition.

Comment: You don't have a "sdb2" partition (and that image is horrible, please use command line tools and cut/paste text): it's an extended partition, so you have 3 partitions, 2x FAT and 1x ext4. You didn't tell us anything about which partition is used for what. So the best advice I can give you: Make a new USB stick with a single partition, copy everything over.

Comment: @dirkt oh sorry, if you click on the image it's much clearer. 
sdb1 is the normal USB storage, sdb6 is Linux installation & home directory? Idk about sdb5 though. But thank you for the recommendation of just copying over, seems ways less work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the partitions is going to be a substantial pain in the nether regions. The problem here is **how does boot happen**. I suspect that is the SDB5 512 meg area's doing. There is also probably some boot code that tells the system to start from sdb5.

But this means that something in that boot block "knows" that the Linux install is in sdb6, so **you don't dare change that**.

## Easiest way out (two USB devices)

Get a new USB key and plug both. Boot from Linux. Format the new USB key the same way but with "better" partitions. Then copy your data from the old key to the new key. Verify that it works. You're done!

## What you can do (with only one USB device)

Linux has, as you probably know, mount points! You can mix and match *those*! So:

- **MAKE A BACKUP OF ANYTHING IMPORTANT**
- boot in Linux and log in as **root** in single ("recovery") mode
- destroy the content of sdb1 partition by reformatting it as ext4:

  mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1
- now inspect your Linux installation and see what is taking up space:

  du -sk /* 2>/dev/null | sort -n

On my test system I have for example (after several seconds of disk scanning):

```
...smaller fry removed...
12220   /run
13320   /sbin
18992   /etc
125244  /boot
873108  /home
873324  /lib
1154900 /opt
1537488 /root
4648100 /usr
15088048        /var
```

So I mostly use my system for /var. Perfect. I'll move /var.

- mount the newly formatted sdb1 onto /mnt

  mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
- copy "/var" onto "/mnt" (so, check that you have rsync installed before even starting)

  rsync -a /var /mnt
- now (this is what should be done in "single mode", text mode boot, with all service stopped; chances are that you won't even be able to do it otherwise)

  mv /var /oldvar # So you can go back if needed, restoring oldvar to var
- recreate a new /var

  mkdir /var
- Check permission on oldvar and replicate them on the new /var
- add a line with sdb1 to the mount point list in /etc/fstab:

  echo "/dev/sdb1 /var   ext4   auto  0  2" >> /etc/fstab

Now every time you boot, the sdb1 partition will be linked to /var, and you will be able to store up to 17 GiB of data on that.

If you now reboot, everything should work as before, you'll see a full /var, and no free space at all on sdb6 since it's being taken up by oldvar. **Check thoroughly that everything works**. When you're sure, delete the oldvar directory and all its subdirectories.

**NOTE**: my example used /var. You might see you need to move /home instead. Same thing. Or you can go deeper than one level and see what is taking up space *inside* /var:

du -sk /var/* 2> /dev/null | sort -n

and in my case I see that it's /var/www that takes up 90% of the space. So I don't need to relocate the whole of /var, I can do the steps above using "/var/www" and still reap 90% of the benefits. Also now I don't need logging in into single mode or to reboot because on my system /var/www is surely only used by the Apache HTTP server, which I can stop and restart without rebooting (while /var/log, /var/run, /var/mail etc. might be in use and require single mode):

```
apache2ctl stop
rsync -a /var/www /mnt
mv /var/www /var/oldwww
mkdir /var/www
# Set up the same ownership and permissions of the old /var/www
chown www-data:users /var/www  
chmod 775 /var/www
# Compare the two ls lines
ls -la /var | grep www
# If ownership and pemissions are OK go on
echo "/dev/sdb1 /var/www   ext4   auto  0  2" >> /etc/fstab
# Free up sdb1 from mnt
umount /mnt
# Check whether the automount from fstab works
mount /var/www
# Now everything is as before, www is there and useable, it's just on sdb1.
apache2ctl start
# Now verify everything works again. IF it works, oldwww is useless.
rm -rf /var/oldwww # kill the original www
```

(I could also have created straight on the new /var/www, mounted it, and rsynced oldww to www, without involving /mnt at all).